# List Google Group's emails with Gmail API Users.messages

Tags: gmail-api, google-groups

is it possible to load emails sent to google group via API?
I can see something like that in Gmail API: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list
but not sure if it will work for google groups.
When I tried it I just got "Delegation denied for..." error.

What I need is to periodically load emails (possibly with attachments) from more google groups (so it is not convenient to resend all emails to some regular gmail address...) - any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For the question is it possible to load emails sent to google group via API?

I think there is no API that allows reading a message in Google Group.
So the alternative way is to use a Gmail account which is a member of that group. By using this Gmail you can check all the message that is sent to that group.

About the Delegation Denied error, this message will be sent if the initiator, in response to a credential request message, is unwilling to generate the requested credential.

Check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26135310/gmail-api-returns-403-error-code-and-delegation-denied-for-user-email) for more information.