# Forward Mail to Alias Google account using Gmail API

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps, gmail-api

I want to forward certain mails from my primary Gmail account to alias Gmail account. But the forwarded mail should retain the "From" field i.e the mail id of the original sender.

I tried adding the alias mail id in the Insert/Send API url call, but it returns "
***Delegation denied for primary email id***".

Also I tried to modify the "To field" (not changing the sender's email id in the From field) in the email content to the alias email id but it always sends the mail from my primary account.

So is there a way to forward a mail to the Alias Google account while retaining the sender's information in the From field.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gmail API returns 403 error code and "Delegation denied for <user email>"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26135310/gmail-api-returns-403-error-code-and-delegation-denied-for-user-email)

Comment: @Danee, I had already checked the above question. None of the answer worked for me and also my query is bit different